# how to make my podcast dropdown tab align with the projects tab above it on my navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a dropdown menu for my navbar, and I can't figure out how to align my dropdown menu with the navbar, it keeps going sideways

```js
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("topnavi").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("mydb2").classList.toggle("show2");
  document.getElementById("mydb").classList.toggle("hide");
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("dropbutton2").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("dropdown2").classList.toggle("width");
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #9e2118;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 148px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #9e2118;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="topnavi">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="art.html">Art</a>
  <a href="resources.html">Resources</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="proj.html" class="dropbtn">Projects &nbsp;&#8964;</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="podcast.html">Podcast</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
```

I tried to use flexbox but when I make the display flex, the element just disappears and I also have no idea why it does that.

https://replit.com/@skylarhiya/navbar#index.html

New to stack, I have no idea how the the snippet code thing works, so here's the link to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed float and make added flex

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #9e2118;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display:flex;
  left:0px
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 148px;
  background-color: #9e2118;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="topnavi">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="art.html">Art</a>
  <a href="resources.html">Resources</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="proj.html" class="dropbtn">Projects</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="podcast.html">Podcast</a>
      <a href="podcast.html">Podcast 1</a>
      <a href="podcast.html">Podcast 2</a>
      <a href="podcast.html">Podcast 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: would there be any way to keep the about tab at the end instead of the projects ? in this order : home|art|resources|project|about